# How to define two fields "unique" as couple

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to define a couple of fields as unique in Django?

I have a table of volumes (of journals) and I don't want more then one volume number for the same journal.

```
class Volume(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    journal_id = models.ForeignKey(Journals, db_column='jid', null=True, verbose_name = "Journal")
    volume_number = models.CharField('Volume Number', max_length=100)
    comments = models.TextField('Comments', max_length=4000, blank=True)
```

I tried to put `unique = True` as attribute in the fields `journal_id` and `volume_number` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 942, accepted):

There is a simple solution for you called [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) which does exactly what you want.

**For example:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('field1', 'field2',)
```

**And in your case:**

```
class Volume(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  journal_id = models.ForeignKey(Journals, db_column='jid', null=True, verbose_name = "Journal")
  volume_number = models.CharField('Volume Number', max_length=100)
  comments = models.TextField('Comments', max_length=4000, blank=True)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('journal_id', 'volume_number',)
```

Comment: How can I check, what exception will be thrown, when I try to create an object that breaks this constraint?

Comment: I would say you'll get a "ValidationError" exception. Have a look at the Django docs: Model.validate_unique

Comment: How would you handle this say if volume_number could be null?  Mysql won't seem to enforce unique in that case.

Comment: FYI it throws a django.db.utils.IntegrityError if you try to add a duplicate.

Comment: @Greg - According to the ANSI standard SQL:2003 (and previous ones as well), a `UNIQUE` constraint should disallow duplicate non-`NULL` values, but allow multiple `NULL` values (see draft http://www.wiscorp.com/sql_2003_standard.zip, Framework, p. 22). If you want your unique constraint to disallow multiple null values, you are probably doing something wrong, like using `NULL` as a meaningfull value. Remember, nullable field says "We don't always have a value for that field but when we do it must be unique.".

Comment: What about multiple `unique_together` constraints? For example - when I want to have mode columns to be unique in the scope of the parent? Well, this property is actually a tuple itself, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together So your constraint should be more explicitly written as: `unique_together = (('journal_id', 'volume_number',),)`.

Comment: This set  journal_id null=False

Comment: @araneae that's strange: you are right even if documentation says "The ValidationError raised during model validation when the constraint is violated has the unique_together error code."

Comment: Is it possible to check unique together from 2 models? eg: I have a field a model A and b in Model B, and want to check the combintion of a and b is unique.

Comment: Wow.. Django continues to amaze me with how easy it makes coding business logic!

Comment: Use UniqueConstraint with the constraints option instead.

UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together. unique_together may be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 237):

### Django 2.2+

Using the [`constraints`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints) features [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) is preferred over **unique_together**.

From the Django documentation for [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

> Use UniqueConstraint with the constraints option instead.
>   UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together.
>   unique_together may be deprecated in the future.

**For example:**

```
class Volume(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    journal_id = models.ForeignKey(Journals, db_column='jid', null=True, verbose_name="Journal")
    volume_number = models.CharField('Volume Number', max_length=100)
    comments = models.TextField('Comments', max_length=4000, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['journal_id', 'volume_number'], name='name of constraint')
        ]
```

Comment: In what situation would the 'name' parameter of the UniqueConstraint be used for? I assume it works like the name parameter of a URL path?

Comment: @user7733611 naming the constraint can be helpful in a number of situations. For example if you are connecting to a legacy database, or if you just want the constraint names to be more human readable in the database. One time I migrated the character set of a MySQL database and Django's generated constraint names were actually too long for our particular target.

Comment: Not 100% sure it comes from `UniqueConstraint` but I get weird `psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "name_of_the_constraint" already exists` when I switch to Postgres

Comment: It should be noted that text fields like `CharField` can be case sensitive or case insensitive depending on your database configurations!

Answer (score 15):

in Django 4.0,

> The new *expressions positional argument of UniqueConstraint() enables
> creating functional unique constraints on expressions and database
> functions. For example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import UniqueConstraint
from django.db.models.functions import Lower


class MyModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                Lower('first_name'),
                Lower('last_name').desc(),
                name='first_last_name_unique',
            ),
        ]
```

Comment: As of Django 4.1, you can now specify a `validation_error_message` argument in your constraint function.

Comment: It's actually `violation_error_message` in case anybody is looking ... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#violation-error-message

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can define more than one field as unique using Django class Meta as this example:

```py
class Volume(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    journal_id = models.ForeignKey(Journals, db_column='jid', null=True, verbose_name = "Journal")
    volume_number = models.CharField('Volume Number', max_length=100)
    comments = models.TextField('Comments', max_length=4000, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('volume_number', 'journal_id')
```

**Note:**
To make things go writes you should not add attribute `unique=True` to any field that you define in `unique_together` attribute otherwise it will not work as unique together.

Comment: As noted by other answers, this method is now deprecated in favor of using constraints such as `UniqueConstraint`.

Answer (score 4):

**In Django 4.1.1**

```
from django.db import models

class Volume(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField("field 1", max_length=100,)
    field_2 = models.CharField("field 2", max_length=100,)
    field_3 = models.CharField("field 3", max_length=100,)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['field_1', 'field_2']]
```

Comment: For convenience, unique_together can be a single list when dealing with a single set of fields: ```unique_together = ['field_1', 'field_2']```