# 2 fields unique

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class blog(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    mail = models.EmailField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want that (user,email) are unique togheter. For example:

This is allowed:

- 1, hello@hello.com, myblog
- 2, hello@hello.com, secondblog

This is NOT allowed:

- 1, hello@hello.com, myblog
- 1, hello@hello.com, secondblog

Is this possible in Django ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201598/django-how-to-define-two-fields-unique-as-couple

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible, see: model options,

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models. ...
    email = models. ...

    # ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "email"),)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Meta.unique_together`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)