# Django - create a unique database constraint for 2 or more fields together

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose, I want to record say poll choices by users everyday. In this case, i have a table named `vote` which has columns `poll` , `choice` and `user-id` . So how can i out the constraint (maybe in the django models or wherever possible) that `poll` and `user-id` both should not be the same for any entry but like the same user can vote for various different polls once and obviously various users can vote for the same poll. I hope I am clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define two fields "unique" as couple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201598/how-to-define-two-fields-unique-as-couple)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[unique_together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 48):

The `unique_together` attribute of the `Meta` class of your model is what you are looking for:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('poll', 'user_id')
```

Check [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) for more information.

Comment: You'll need a comma between the two close parentheses I think `unique_together = (('poll', 'user_id'),)`.

Comment: Actually it's not needed: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Answer (score 41):

Django 2.2 introduced `UniqueConstraint` and the note in the [official documentation on this topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) suggests that `unique_together` might be deprecated in future. See deprecation note [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

You can add `UniqueConstraint` to the `Meta.constraints` option of your model class like so:

```py
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['poll', 'user_id'], name="user-polled")
        ]
```

Comment: **Older Django versions (eg. 2.0.6)** are not supported, I think. Or is there a work around?

Comment: There's `unique_together` as suggested in the other answers. Django 2.0 is out of support btw, if you can update it do that! https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions

Comment: Why is the usage of `uniqueTogether` not shown in the documentation? I had to come here to find I have to have it in a list called `constraints`, in the `Meta` class of the model

Answer (score 2):

You want the `unique_together` attribute: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: As far as I know, you can suggest an edit to this answer if it doesn't please you in some way. That will then be accepted, assuming your suggested edit isn't crap, and you will have contributed something positive to the world. Downvoting an answer that's 3 years old when the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2881073/111777) is still correct seems a bit unnecessary, but I guess it's your prerogative.

Comment: You have to agree that answer that is just one sentence with link and this link is broken is not a really good answer, is it? :) Contrary there is upvoted one that is acceptect and link is correct. That's why one I value other I don't.