# Django model unique together both ways

Tags: python, django, django-models, unique-constraint

Many questions already on this topic, but not what i'm searching for.

I have this `Model`:

```
class Options(TimeStampedModel)
    option_1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    option_2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('option_1', 'option_2')
```

Now I have a unique constraint on the fields.
Is there a way to also define this the other way around so that it doesn't matter what was `option_1` and what was `option_2`

As example:

```
Options.create('spam', 'eggs') # Allowed
Options.create('spam', 'eggs') # Not allowed
Options.create('eggs', 'spam') # Is allowed but should not be
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to want to do, what is your specific use case?

Comment: They are options.. and options shouldn't go together more than once, left or rightways

Comment: I feel a better solution might be a many to many relationship and making an Option model.

Comment: You could do that with a CHECK constraint on the database, but then you'll want more options and it will be messy... @etene's solution is more appropriate here

Comment: @Kos How would you do this using a [`CheckConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint)? I'd like to push more validation into the database itself, but using a `ManyToMany` relationship as in @etene's solution below is not an option. The problem I'm finding with `CheckConstraint`'s is they seem to be limited to the data in the row being inserted.

Comment: @phoenix , you should open a separate question about your casus, explaining why the solution below does not satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relation with a custom [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table and an [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) constraint on that table should do what you want.

Example code:

```
from django.db.models import Model, ForeignKey, ManyToManyField, CharField

class Option(Model):
    name = CharField()

class Thing(TimeStampedModel):
    options = ManyToManyField("Option", through="ThingOption")    

class ThingOption(Model):
    thing = ForeignKey(Thing)
    option = ForeignKey(Option)
    value = CharField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('thing', 'option')
```

For Django 2.2+ it is recommended to use [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint). In the docs there is a [note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) stating `unique_together` may be deprecated in the future. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881043/django-create-a-unique-database-constraint-for-2-or-more-fields-together) post for its usage.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the way to go

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this. The options are a field on the `Thing` model. So I can select the 'spam' and 'eggs' `Option` models in that? How does the `ThingOption` table prevent the selection the other way around? And what is `value`?

Comment: This is a bit old for me, but you should probably read the docs I've linked, esp. on many-to-many through tables.
The `ThingOption` table doesn't prevent selection in any way, it just prevents setting the same `Option` more than once for the same `Thing`, through the `unique_together` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can override create method, do something like

```
from django.db import models

class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, *obj_data):
        # Do some extra stuff here on the submitted data before saving...       
        # Ex- If obj_data[0]=="eggs" and obj_data[1]=="spam" is True don't allow it for your blah reason      
        # Call the super method which does the actual creation
        return super().create(*obj_data) # Python 3 syntax!!

class MyModel(models.model):
    option_1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    option_2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    objects = MyModelManager()
```