# How to make unique_together both ways?

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a friend model to save a user and his friend. I am using the following model:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friends = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="friends", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accepted = models.NullBooleanField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'friends')
```

In this model, I am able to save ('User1', 'User2') as well as ('User2, 'User1'), which is not what I want. So, how do I make this relation unique?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49817401/11559079 might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unfortunately.

I've ended up with following solution in similar situation:

```
class Friendship(BaseModel):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(to='users.User',
                               on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                               related_name='sent_friendships',
                               verbose_name=_('Sender'))
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(to='users.User',
                                 on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                 related_name='received_friendships',
                                 verbose_name=_('Receiver'))
    accepted = models.NullBooleanField(_('Accepted'), default=None)
    sender_noticed_result = models.BooleanField(_('Sender noticed result'), default=False,
                                                help_text=_('Shows that sender seen that receiver '
                                                            'accepted/declined the friendship'))

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.sender} to {self.receiver}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    def clean(self):
        if (self.__class__.objects
                .filter(Q(sender_id=self.receiver_id, receiver_id=self.sender_id)
                        | Q(sender_id=self.sender_id, receiver_id=self.receiver_id))
                .exclude(id=self.id).exists()):
            raise ValidationError(_(f"Friendship already declared between {self.sender} and {self.receiver}"))
        if self.sender_id == self.receiver_id:
            raise ValidationError(_("Can't declare friendship to yourself"))
        if self.sender_noticed_result and self.accepted is None:
            raise ValidationError(_("Can't notice not yet accepted/declined friendship"))

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi can you please explain me the first if condition of def clean()?

Comment: if a Friendship other than current one where one of 2 users sends a friendship request to other user, we raise a validation error saying one of them already proposed the other one  being friends.

We want only one friendship relation between 2 users, disregarding who declared it. So it pretty much has `unique_together` both ways on application layer.

Comment: If you look closely it means(Q(user1=user1, user2=user2) or Q(user1=user2, user2=user1))

Answer (score 0):

@ serializers.py

```
class FriendshipCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Friendship
    fields = [ 'id', 'sender', 'receiver']
    # you can use Serializer default validator for dulplicate user invites
    validators = [
        UniqueTogetherValidator(
            queryset=Friendship.objects.all(),
            fields=('sender', 'receiver'),
            message=_("You already sent an invite to this user")
        )
    ]

# and validate for invitee(already invited) to not be able to send a request
def validate(self, data):
    has_received_an_invite = Friendship.objects.all().filter(
        sender=data['receiver'], 
        receiver=data['sender']
    ).exists()
    if has_received_an_invite :
        raise serializers.ValidationError("User already sent you an invite.")
    return data
```

-- both can be done in validate method