# How to make a Django UniqueConstraint that checks fields in a position-independant way?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation, django-constraints

I have a Django `Model` where I'd like to ensure that no duplicate `Edge` exists where the same pair of `Node`s appear as `node_a` or `node_b`, in either order.

```py
class Edge(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="edges", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    node_a = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name="+", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    node_b = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name="+", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=("project", "node_a", "node_b"), name="unique_edge"
            ),
        ]
```

This catches if an `Edge` is made with the same `(A, B)`, but not if the same `Node`s are put in reverse `(B, A)`.

The validation function I'm trying to port to [Constraint`s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/) was:

```py
    def validate_unique(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        if self.project.edges.filter(
            Q(node_a=self.node_a_id, node_b=self.node_b_id)
            | Q(node_a=self.node_b_id, node_b=self.node_a_id)
        ).exists():
            raise ValidationError(
                f"Edges must be unique within a project: {self.node_a_id}|{self.node_b_id}"
            )
```

This validation function validates that the `Node`s are unique in both directions: `(A, B)` or `(B, A)`.

Is there a way to express this within a [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint)?

Currently targeting Django 4.1.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816979