# Django: Constraint on multiple model fields

Tags: python, django

Example:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    def _get_full_name(self):
       return '{0} {1}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

   full_name = property(_get_full_name)
```

What's the recommended way of putting a unique constaint on the full_name? Was thinking of overwriting save but maybe there are better solutions?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201598/django-how-to-define-two-fields-unique-as-couple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Meta class option [unique_together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

You could do it this way:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    def _get_full_name(self):
       return '{0} {1}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    full_name = property(_get_full_name)

    class Meta: 
       unique_together = ("first_name", "last_name")
```

The advantage is that this is enforced at the DB level with the proper UNIQUE SQL statements.

Comment: It is probably the solution required, but there are edge cases that this won't pick up as a conflict: "'bob' 'brown smith'" and "'bob brown' 'smith'". Full name is the same, but last_name and first_name are different.

Answer (score 2):

[unique_together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

unique_together = ("first_name", "last_name")