# Django model ensuring two properties should always be different - Is unique_together the answer?

Tags: django, django-models

How do I ensure that a unique combination of two properties should not be repeated

For instance in the following model

```
class modelBodyPart(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    crush_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

In each instance of modelBodyPart `area` and `crush_name` should always be different

for example some allowed and non-allowed results are:

```
  area = Area_A crush_name=Jenny //OK
  area = Area_A crush_name=Jordan //OK
  area = Area_B crush_name=Jenny //OK
  area = Area_A crush_name=Jenny //Not allowed
```

How would I implement this in the model ? Will I use  [unique_together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201598/how-to-define-two-fields-unique-as-couple)
I could not totally understand the case requirement from the above link that is why I am asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right your code should be like this -

**models.py**

```
class modelBodyPart(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    crush_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
         unique_together = ['area','crush_name']
```