# Django model prevent Duplicate based on two variables

Tags: django, django-models

I need to make sure the entry does not have the same project and case id.

How is the best way to prevent a duplicate entry?

Here the project can not have the same case twice.

```
class Cases(models.Model ):

    project = models.ForeignKey ( Project, on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    case = models.ForeignKey ( Case, on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    active = models.BooleanField ( default = 1 )
```

Thank you.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201598/how-to-define-two-fields-unique-as-couple

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unique_together` in `Meta` class in you model as below.

```
class Cases(models.Model ):

    project = models.ForeignKey ( Project, on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    case = models.ForeignKey ( Case, on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    active = models.BooleanField ( default = 1 )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('project', 'case')
```

This will set unique constraint on `project_id` and `case_id`.