# Django REST validator. Multiple users can have records with same value, but that record is unique for each user, how to do that?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to accomplish the following with Django REST framework.
I have model Records, which has  field. It has foreign key to User. Each user can create multiple records with different numbers, but cannot create more than one record with the same number for themselves. However, each other user can create a record for itself with same number.
E.g. Users Joe and Jill.
Joe can create a record with number 123 only once, if he tries to make another record with 123, he should not be allowed. However Jill can create 123 once for herself, but not allowed more again.

My guess is to create a validator inside the serializer, which is

```
class RecordSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    '''Serializer for Record'''

    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = [
            'user', 
            'number', 
            'otherfield', 
        ]

        validators = [
            UniqueValidator(
                queryset= Record.objects.filter(user=<current user>),
            )
        ]
```

However, I cannot get the current user inside validator property, or how can I accomplish this otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the constraint both in the serializer level and model level just in case a record is created outside the serializer. 
So let's say the record has `id` and `owner` fields, add the `unique_together` property in the model's Meta class:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (('id', 'owner'))
```

Then in the serializer, you can use the [CurrentUserDefault](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) advanced field to capture the logged-in user.

```
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator


class RecordSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )

    class Meta:
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Record.objects.all(),
                fields=['id', 'owner']
            )
        ]
```

Of course, the serializer should be used in a view which requires authentication

Comment: Guys! @Andee and @Ken4Sholars! thanks so much! I have spent a whole day finding a solution!

Comment: This answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55786819/7027427 points that UniqueConstraints should be preferred over unique_together, and that can be deprecated. Also I am getting <django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:> error pointing to those fields, when migrating.

Comment: Yes, that is just the preferred way of specifying the unique constraints in the new versions of Django, so if you have such a version, please go ahead and use that instead of `unique_together`. As for the `IntegrityError`, it seems you are violating the unique constraint. That's exactly how it notifies the developer that it is being violated. I suspect that you are creating the record outside the serializer. Means that user already has a record with that number. Also, you may want to rename the `id` field in my answer to the number field you described in the question

Comment: I had records violating the constraint in the db. removed them and fixed :) thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 1):

On your model Meta, set unique_together https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together