# Django Models how to add unique constraint

Tags: django, django-models

Unsimilar to for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201598/how-to-define-two-fields-unique-as-couple) case I am trying to allow only one entry in a database for one user:

```
class Station(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField("serial", max_length = 31, unique = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, )
```

What I want is that one user can only have zero or one Station (serial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a [one-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/). This means a user can have zero or exactly one station.

```py
class Station(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField("serial", max_length = 31, unique = True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Comment: can I edit the message a user sees when trying to add a second serial?

Comment: I think this depends on your use case. Are you using model forms, Django Rest framework, or something else?

Comment: I was more thinking about the admin tbh.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`unique=true`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#unique) on your ForeignKey,
but you do have wrong relationship type as you should have [One-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a
> ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation
> will directly return a single object.

```
class Station(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField("serial", max_length=31, unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```