# How to put a constraint using foreign key fields in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, model

Consider following models:

```
class Model1:
    x = an integer
    y = an integer

class Model2:
    f1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    f2 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
```

Now, I want to put a constraint on model 2 such that no duplicate pairs of f1.x and f2.x get inserted in model 2.

How should I achieve it? I will be populating model 2 using bulk_create so maybe customising clean() or save() won't work.

I'm new to Django and not able to figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

There another similar question here: [How to define two fields "unique" as couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201598/how-to-define-two-fields-unique-as-couple)

But it's not helpful in my case.

Comment: @solarissmoke how can I access the x field of Model1 from model2 in unique constraint?

Comment: Why do you think the other answer won't work for you?

Comment: @Art because I need to access the field from foreign key i.e. I need to access x from f1 and from f2 for setting the constraint. How can I do that?

Comment: Eg: `Model2.objetcs.filter(f1__x=1)` or `Model2.objects.filter(f1=1)` this will return all the x that is 1 from model2

Comment: I understand that but I need to add a constraint on database level and not application level.