# Unique constraint in my model in my django project?

Tags: python, django

I would like to configure my Teacher model so that I can have several teachers with the same name, the same age but different departments
How to do ?

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=70)
    age=models.IntegerField()
    service=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Exemple output on my database :

```
Name                   Age                     Service
Arnaud                 29                      Science
Carmen                 37                      Medecine
Arnaud                 29                      Geologie
Carmen                 37                      Science
```

Comment: Try unique=False.

Comment: in which field ?

Comment: `service=models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)`

Comment: With that, will I not have duplicate information with the same name, same age and same service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define two fields "unique" as couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201598/how-to-define-two-fields-unique-as-couple)

Comment: Do note that ideally none of these fields that you show should be unique or unique together with each other. What ends up happening when you coincidentally end up having 2 people with the same name, age **and** department?